Can't install any packages or create environments through Anaconda
I've been trying to install scikit-learn through Spyder and every time I attempt, I get the same error. I also get this error when I try installing in the terminal. Is there something I'm missing? I have Miniconda 3, Spyder 5.5.5, and python 3.10.11.
KeyError('active_prefix_name')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda/exception_handler.py", line 18, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 52, in main_subshell
    from .conda_argparse import do_call, generate_parser, generate_pre_parser
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 51, in <module>
    from .main_create import configure_parser as configure_parser_create
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda/cli/main_create.py", line 16, in <module>
    from ..notices import notices
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda/notices/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .core import notices  # noqa: F401
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda/notices/core.py", line 15, in <module>
    from . import cache, fetch, views
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda/notices/fetch.py", line 11, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 164, in <module>
    from .api import delete, get, head, options, patch, post, put, request
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import sessions
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .adapters import HTTPAdapter
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 76, in <module>
    _preloaded_ssl_context = create_urllib3_context()
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 252, in create_urllib3_context
    raise TypeError("Can't create an SSLContext object without an ssl module")
TypeError: Can't create an SSLContext object without an ssl module

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda/exception_handler.py", line 165, in print_unexpected_error_report
    get_main_info_str(error_report["conda_info"])
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda/cli/main_info.py", line 399, in get_main_info_str
    return "\n".join(("", *(f"{key:>23} : {value}" for key, value in builder()), ""))
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda/cli/main_info.py", line 399, in <genexpr>
    return "\n".join(("", *(f"{key:>23} : {value}" for key, value in builder()), ""))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda/cli/main_info.py", line 359, in builder
    if info_dict["active_prefix_name"]:
       ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'active_prefix_name'

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda/exception_handler.py", line 18, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 52, in main_subshell
        from .conda_argparse import do_call, generate_parser, generate_pre_parser
      File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 51, in <module>
        from .main_create import configure_parser as configure_parser_create
      File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda/cli/main_create.py", line 16, in <module>
        from ..notices import notices
      File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda/notices/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
        from .core import notices  # noqa: F401
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda/notices/core.py", line 15, in <module>
        from . import cache, fetch, views
      File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda/notices/fetch.py", line 11, in <module>
        import requests
      File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 164, in <module>
        from .api import delete, get, head, options, patch, post, put, request
      File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 11, in <module>
        from . import sessions
      File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 15, in <module>
        from .adapters import HTTPAdapter
      File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 76, in <module>
        _preloaded_ssl_context = create_urllib3_context()
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 252, in create_urllib3_context
        raise TypeError("Can't create an SSLContext object without an ssl module")
    TypeError: Can't create an SSLContext object without an ssl module

`$ /opt/miniconda3/bin/conda install scikit-learn`

  environment variables:
conda info could not be constructed.
KeyError('active_prefix_name')

An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
If you suspect this error is being caused by a malfunctioning plugin,
consider using the --no-plugins option to turn off plugins.

Example: conda --no-plugins install <package>

Alternatively, you can set the CONDA_NO_PLUGINS environment variable on
the command line to run the command without plugins enabled.

Example: CONDA_NO_PLUGINS=true conda install <package>

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers? [y/N]: 
Timeout reached. No report sent.

I have tried creating a new environment and I receive the same message.

Can't create an SSLContext object without an ssl module implies to me your system doesn't ahve / has the wrong version of an ssl library installed. That's just a guess on my part but it looks like conda is attmepting to use https to download the package and it's failing

You need to install it via the command prompt within a conda environment, not through Spyder.
